# Random factors giving me trouble in running a statistical model in R

Tags: r, statistics, sample

I am simulating a data set and running a statistical test on it. I have a random factor (id), which accounts for the fact that each participant has two data points. The sample is 1000. Every 2-3 times in an iteration of 10, the statistical test cannot be made (NaNs are generated). Yet, if I remove the random factor, everything works fine. The thing is that I think it would be more statistically correct to run the model with random factors, so I would like to understand what is the source of the problem. Below, there is an example of this happening, with a sample of 100. In the first sample of 100, random factors cannot be included. In the second sample of 100, they can. Can anyone figure out what is going on?

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)
library(ordinal)
id=factor(rep(1:50, each=2))
treat <- factor(rep(c(0,1),times=2))
datasocial0 <- data.frame(id,treat)
datasocial0$dispersal <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                          1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
datasocial0$sex <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
                    0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
                    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                    1)
datasocial0$risk <- c(3, 7, 2, 9, 1, 6, 2, 6, 3, 7, 3, 9, 4, 9, 3, 9, 4, 7, 5, 7, 2, 6, 1, 7, 4, 9, 4, 8, 4, 7, 6, 9, 1,
                      8, 2, 8, 5, 7, 2, 9, 2, 8, 4, 9, 0, 8, 2, 9, 2, 9, 3, 9, 1, 9, 1, 9, 3, 8, 3, 9, 4, 9, 1, 8, 1, 9, 
                      3, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9, 2, 9, 3, 9, 4, 7, 5, 7, 1, 8, 4, 8, 5, 9, 0, 8, 1, 7, 5, 8, 7, 8, 3,
                      9)
datasocial0$risk <- as.factor(datasocial0$risk)
test0 <- clmm(risk ~ treat + sex + dispersal + sex*dispersal + treat*dispersal + treat*sex + (1 | id), data = datasocial0, Hess=TRUE)
summary(test0)
test00 <- clm(risk ~ treat + sex + dispersal + sex*dispersal + treat*dispersal + treat*sex, data = datasocial0, Hess=TRUE)
summary(test00)

id=factor(rep(1:50, each=2))
treat <- factor(rep(c(0,1),times=2))
datasocial1 <- data.frame(id,treat)
datasocial1$dispersal <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                           1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                           0, 0, 0, 0)
datasocial1$sex <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
                     1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)
datasocial1$risk <- c(3, 9, 2, 8, 1, 8, 1, 7, 4, 8, 5, 8, 4, 7, 2, 7, 3, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 8, 4, 8, 1, 6, 4, 8, 2, 9, 2, 7, 
                      4, 8, 7, 6, 3, 9, 3, 8, 6, 8, 5, 8, 3, 9, 2, 8, 4, 6, 4, 8, 3, 7, 4, 7, 3, 9, 4, 9, 3, 5, 3, 9, 3, 9, 
                      4, 9, 3, 6, 1, 7, 4, 7, 4, 8, 2, 7, 3, 9, 3, 9, 4, 7, 2, 7, 4, 8, 3, 7, 3, 9, 4, 9, 4, 7, 2, 9)
datasocial1$risk <- as.factor(datasocial1$risk)
test1 <- clmm(risk ~ treat + sex + dispersal + sex*dispersal + treat*dispersal + treat*sex + (1 | id), data = datasocial1, Hess=TRUE)
summary(test1)
test11 <- clm(risk ~ treat + sex + dispersal + sex*dispersal + treat*dispersal + treat*sex, data = datasocial1, Hess=TRUE)
summary(test11)
```

Comment: I don't know whether this is related to your issue but `sex*dipersal` is a shortcut for `sex + dispersal + sex:dispersal`. So, unless this is automatically handled, you include several times the same factors.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of having very few observations for some combinations of `id, sex, treat` in your `datasocial0`. If you try to run `datasocial0 = rbind(datasocial0, datasocial0)` (which just duplicates your dataset) just before you build your `test0` model you'll see that you have no issues.

Comment: @Stephane's solution works for me. That is, `test0 <- clmm(risk ~ sex*dispersal + treat*dispersal + treat*sex + (1 | id), data = datasocial0, Hess=TRUE)` works. Which surprises me a little.